# Unable to search for Orders/Customers in oracle commerce (ATG) - CSC 11.1

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I am trying to perform order and profile search operations on CSC, but they return no results.

I  the components /atg/commerce/textsearch/OrderOutputConfig/ and /atg/userprofiling/textsearch/ProfileOutputConfig/ and I found them indexing perfectly in the tables **SRCH_ORDER_TOKENS** and **SRCH_PROFILE_TOKENS** respectively.

After enabling loggingDebug in both components I found that the search query has additional condition seems that it's related to multisite **pfrmZeroRealmsAccessible**, however I found that all tokens stored in DB for orders and customers have this value **pfrmdft**. Below is the query extracted from logs:

```
[++SQLQuery++]
SELECT t1.id
   FROM srch_order_tokens t1
  WHERE CONTAINS(t1.tokens,?,0) > 0
-- Parameters --
p[1] = {pd: tokens} pflnAhmad% AND pfrmZeroRealmsAccessible% (java.lang.String)
[--SQLQuery--]
```

**Note:** My application has only one single site (not multisite) however I found some configuration files created by CIM related to multisite which I can't remove.

**Please help me answering the following question:**

1. Is this issue really related to multisite configuration and how can I fix this problem in orders and customers search?
2. In Oracle commerce 11.1 how can I disable working with multisite?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not configured multi site then you need change the property "siteAccessControlOn" to false in the below component
/atg/commerce/custsvc/environment/CSREnvironmentTools/

for more details you can get back to the below oracle docs link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_01/Service.11-1/ATGCommerceServiceCenterInstall/html/s1203controllingsiteaccess01.html